# calculating unstandardised betas for categorical predictors

Tags: statistics

I am trying to calculate the unstandardised beta for a categorical variable in a linear regression model

y ~ c + βx1

where y (on the original scale) has a mean of 1000ms and a standard deviation 80 ms.

x1 is categorical and takes on two values as 0 or 1.

The **standardised** beta is 0.14

Is there a way i can derive the beta on the original scale and what formula would i use.

I can find several references to the formula for transforming betas for continuous covariates but not for categorical ones.

Thank you

Comment: Interesting question, but off topic here; try stats.stackexchange.com instead.